# how to get id of component to be rendered

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using a template to display a drop down menu on all my pages. I want to render only menu items that a specific user is allowed to access.

```
<rich:menuGroup label="Items" id="item" rendered="#{user.allowed">
  <rich:menuItem label="Find" action="searchItems"/>
  <rich:menuItem label="Create" action="newItem"/>
</rich:menuGroup>
<rich:menuGroup label="Groups" id="group" rendered="#{user.allowed">
  <rich:menuItem label="Find" action="searchGroup"/>
  <rich:menuItem label="Create" action="newGroup"/>
</rich:menuGroup>
```

allowed() is designed to be a universal method. It calls

```
String id = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getId();
```

to get the id of the component so that it can decide whether or not to render the item.

Unfortunately, the id returned is not that of the menuGroup; instead it is the container that holds the menuGroup. Since it's the enclosing container, this component has a list of its children and a component with the id of "item" is in that list. My problem is that I can't figure out which child the method "allowed" is being called for, i.e. this item, "item", or one of the other children in the list. Is there some way of asking the parent container which child "allowed()" is being called on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass the id to the bean directly?

```
<rich:menuGroup label="Groups" id="group" rendered="#{user.isAllowed('group')}">
```

Comment: sigh. because I tried that once and it didn't work. my confusion was that when you specify a method without an argument, it automatically preprends "is" so that #{user.allowed} calls the method "isAllowed". when you add the argument, i.e. #{user.allowed('group')} it calls "allowed" without the "is". thanks very much.